# how I can retrieve my last insert row from table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating a bmi application. this is veeery simple apps which user must enter name, weight and height. then, it will insert into database name bmi. after user click button calculate, it will calculate the bmi based on name that user had entered. how can i retrieve it since the last i tried is they read the first row from the database. how can i retrieve the last row?

here is code:

DataHelper.java

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "assignment.db";
//Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Create constructor for Data Helper
public DataHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table bmi(name text primary key, weight double null, height double null);";
    Log.d("Data", "onCreate: " + sql);
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

//create method to upgrade database version if database exist
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
}
```

CalculateActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

    dbHelper = new DataHelper(this);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);
    text3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
    ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

   ton1.setOnClickListener(arg0 -> {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL("insert into bmi(name, weight, height) values ('" +
                text1.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text3.getText().toString() + "')");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       Intent i = new Intent(CalculateActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    });
}
```

ResultActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    dbHelper = new DataHelper(this);

    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    text3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
    textname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    textTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBMITotal);
    textBMI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBMI);
    textRisk = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtRisk);

    bye = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBye);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bmi ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();





    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        cursor.moveToPosition(0);

//below i just want to know whether it retrieved or not
        textTotal.setText(cursor.getString(0).toString());
        textBMI.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
        textRisk.setText(cursor.getString(2).toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: If *you* inserted it, why would you have to read it by running a query?

Comment: i want to display the total of bmi by calculating the bmi from weight and height, that's why i want to read it, actually, textTotal, textBMI, and textRisk are the textview , which can be displayed when calculate the bmi.

Comment: what goose means is that you calculate it first, before you insert it. You have the values there. Why insert it, then take it out from db again? Redundant.

Comment: anyway, if you want to find the last inserted id, you would usually need a timestamp column. but in this case, its grossly unnecessary since you already have access to the data outside the db.

Comment: @nerdgirl do you actually need to use a db ? if you need to calculate the bmi on the fly, then you don't need to store anything. if you need to keep track of the bmi of only one user then you can use shared preferences, you only need to use db if you want to store multiple bmi values for different names and in this case you can calculate bmi first before storing it, like g00se and YHStan said.

Comment: ohhhh i think i got it. i need to calculate bmi first before storing it.. why i made it complicated hmm. thank you g00se, YHStan, and Mohamed Shannan.

Mohamed Shannan, i need to use a db actually to user reuse their latest data when they reopen the application, which mean the last row inserted.

so, like YHStan said, i need to add timestamp column?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is pass the **name** to the ResultActivity via an Intent Extra and then extract the Intent Extra in the ResultActivty and then use the name to extract the row from the bmi table.

So in **CalculateActivity.java**

use :-

```
ton1.setOnClickListener(arg0 -> {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("insert into bmi(name, weight, height) values ('" +
            text1.getText().toString() + "','" +
            text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
            text3.getText().toString() + "')");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   Intent i = new Intent(CalculateActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("name_extra",text1.getText().toString()); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    startActivity(i);
});
```

And in **ResultActivity** :-

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bmi WHERE name=? ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 1", new String[]{this.getIntent().getStringExtra("name_extra")});
if (cursor.MoveToFirst()) {
    textTotal.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
    textBMI.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("weight")));
    textRisk.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("height")));
} else {
    // Do something here to indicate nothing retrieved 
}
```

- Note the changed query to select according to the passed value (no need for ORDER BY clause as name is the PRIMARY KEY and thus MUST be unique).
- the Cursor's `moveToFirst` method will return true if the move was successful, false if not (e.g. no rows). So you just need `moveToFirst` no need to check the count as well.
- using the Cursor's `getColumnIndex(the_column_name)` method is more flexible than hard coding specific index offsets.
- No need to use the `toString` method of a String to get a String.

> ohhhh i think i got it. i need to calculate bmi first before storing it

You don't need to store an additional value as you could actually do the calculation via the query, so there is no need to store the additional value. So your query could be something like :-

```
`SELECT *, (weight/height)/height AS bmi_value FROM bmi WHERE name=?;`
.....
textBMI.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bmi_value")));
```

- The resultant Cursor will contain all the columns in the table ( the `*`) plus an aditional derived (calculated) column who's column name is bmi_value (due to the `AS` clause).
- this assumes that the BMI will be displayed via a TextView object named `textBMI`
- Note that perhaps the more correctly query should be:-

  `SELECT *, (coalesce(weight,1.0)/coalesce(height,1.0))/coalesce(height,1.0) AS bmi_value FROM bmi; WHERE name=?;`
- the coalesce function returns the first NON NULL value from the list of parameters/arguments so if weight or height is NULL then 1.0 is used.
- **Note** the above is in-principle code, it has not been compiled or run and therefore may contain some errors.

**Additional**

Re comments

> what if, under the query in if(moveToFirst()){...}, i want to calculate bmi and display in a condition?

Again you can let the Query do the work using a `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` construct e.g. :-

```
SELECT *, (coalesce(weight,1.0)/coalesce(height,1.0))/coalesce(height,1.0) AS bmi_value, CASE WHEN (coalesce(weight,1.0)/coalesce(height,1.0))/coalesce(height,1.0) <= 20 THEN 'good' ELSE 'Malnutrition risk' END AS bmi_state FROM bmi WHERE name=?
```

- So the Cursor will contain yet another column named **bmi_state** which will be either *good* (bmi <= 20) or *Malnutrition risk*

> Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("weight")))

No need to extract a string and then parse to double. The Cursor has methods for extracting various types so you can use:-

```
cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("weight"))
```

See [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) and all the get???? methods.

**Hint**

When it comes to SQL for SQLite there are various tools (I use Navicat for SQLite, but there are others such as DB Browser for SQlite, DBeaver, SQlite Studio). These tools are great for playing around with the SQL. As an example to provide the above I used the following to formulate/test the above :-

[image]

- Note that I have commented out the WHERE clause to test a few scenarios, including handling nulls.

Comment: awesome sir. i really appreciated it. what if, under the query in if(moveToFirst()){...}, i want to calculate bmi and display in a condition?  like, double calculate = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("weight"))) / (Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("height"))) * Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("height"))));

            if (calculate < 20.0) {
                textTotal.setText("fff");
                textBMI.setText("good");
                textRisk.setText("Malnutrition risk");
            }

Comment: i am not sure whether i can apply this codes or not. because, after i set (calculate > 20.0)**and put values that bmi result is more than 20.0, it cannot read it. so, i assume after what i have done, the calculate result is 0 since the value is 0?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP SIR, REALLY APPRECIATE IT